# Angular - Bootstrap style not working in nested components

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a table with a nested component for rows, here is what I have:

**Parent file:**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>TITLE</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>USER</th>
      <th>OWNER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <app-ticket *ngFor="let ticket of tickets" [ticket]="ticket"></app-ticket>
</table>
```

**app-ticket:**

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
  <td>{{ticket.title}}</td>
  <td>{{ticket.description}}</td>
  <td>{{ticket.email}}</td>
  <td>{{ticket.owner}} <button class="btn btn-warning">TEST</button></td>
</tr>
```

But bootstrap style on rows don't work, I've searched and people suggest putting the tr / td's in the root component, but this is not feasible sometimes, specially with multi-level components, is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to make the component a directive-like component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tr[app-ticket]',
    templateUrl: './app-ticket.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-ticket.component.scss']
})
export class AppTicketComponent {

    @Input() ticket: Ticket;

}
```

html template:

```
<td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
<td>{{ticket.title}}</td>
<td>{{ticket.description}}</td>
<td>{{ticket.email}}</td>
<td>{{ticket.owner}} <button class="btn btn-warning">TEST</button></td>
```

and then use it like this:

```
<tr app-ticket *ngFor="let ticket of tickets" [ticket]="ticket"></tr>
```

This will directly render the tr inside of the table instead of leaving a tag for your component.